# else в цикле спамит всеми строками из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

При совпадении `if` работает нормально, так как надо, выводит одну строку, если этой строки нет, то `else` начинает спамить все строки которые перебирает из файла test.txt
Как сделать, что бы `else` проверяла все строки из файла но при этом выводило только одно единственное значение?

```
i = 0
with open('C:/Users/sk/Desktop/Python3/test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        list_words = line.split()
        i = i + 1
        if a in line:
            print('YES' + ' - ' + line, end='')
        else:
            print('NET')
```

Comment: иначе флаг=1 и после цикла если флаг==1, то принт

Comment: Вам надо проверить, что `a` находится в каждой строке?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов наоборот что `a` нет во всех строках и при этом вести один единственный принт НЕТ. А сейчас выводится на каждую строку из файла принт НЕТ.

Comment: `if not all(a in line.split() for line in file): print("no")`.

Comment: Если надо выводить `"YES"` для каждого вхождения, то логичнее будет после `"NET"` выходить из цикла.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов `if not all(a in line.split() for line in file): print("no")` работает точно так же как мой `else` на каждую строку из файла пишет no.

Comment: @Интик А можно подробнее, попробовал не работает. У меня 7 текстовых файлов когда я делаю `if` `else` либо своим способом или вашим. При совпадении `if` делает принт нужной строки и потом отрабатывает `else` и еще 6 раз печатается NET. Если сразу срабатывает `else` то просто печатает 7 раз NET.

Comment: @sakhalin уточните. требуется чтобы прошла проверка условий и после неё вывести ответ 1 раз да/нет ?

Comment: @Интик что бы прошла условие, и если прошла положительно то напечатала строку, без дополнительный принтов NET. Если не прошла условие, то напечатала бы только один раз NET.

Comment: тогда нужно принт'нет' вывести из цикла.\  делаем переменную net=0 ,в условии после else: пишем net+=1 после завершения for  проверяем if net!=0 то  принтуем там.  допонлнительно после 'нет' можно вывести сколько раз было 'нет'.  @sakhalin

Comment: @Интик )) при любом условии у меня всегда печатаются дополнительные net))) никак не могу от них избавиться. С вашим вариантом тоже)

Comment: значит нужно проверять исходные данные и условие. if a in line переделывайте. чему там 'а' равно ?  @sakhalin

Answer (score 0):

Решил свою проблему так, добавлением `quit()` после принта `if` и вынесением `else` из цикла, всё заработало так как и хотел.

```
    i = 0
    with open('C:/Users/sk/Desktop/Python3/12/result_cisco.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for line in file:
            list_words = line.split()
            i = i + 1
            if a in line:
                print(info['hostname'] + ' - ' + line, end='')
                quit()
else:
    print('net takogo mac-address')
exit()
```

Comment: Чтобы просто прервать выполнение цикла достаточно использовать break

Comment: @insolor Если прерываю цикл break потом продолжается выполнение else вне цикла. А мне нужно остановиться на этом.

Comment: else сам по себе не выполняется - это всегда часть какой-то конструкции. Сейчас вообще не понятно, что у вас там за висячий else.

Comment: @insolor Но работает, сейчас если `if a in line:` я получаю принт этой стройки, и скрипт завершает, то что нужно. Если `if a in line:` не выполняется, то всё таки else отрабатывает, т.к. я получаю принт net takogo mac-address

Comment: Если там снаружи еще один цикл, то можно все обернуть в функцию, и использовать return для выхода из внутреннего цикла.